# Normal form of a function

Tags: functions, notation, normed-spaces

I was given an exercise, where I'm asked to calculate the second normal of a difference between a function $f(x)$ and it's approximation $p(x)$:

$||f-p||_2$

I find this notation to be very confusing, because how can we take the Euclidean norm of a function? (assuming I can mark $f(x)-p(x)=g(x)$ )

In the previous exercises we used the infinite norm for functions, which was defined as $||f(x)||_\infty=max\space |f(x)|$

I was guessing that the valid way to convert it to a continuous operation is to replace the summation in the definition of the norm ($||x||_2=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{|x_i|}}$) to an integral, but I am not sure as to how that is supposed to be done.

Also as a side note, we have this form used as a way to write down the Pythagorean formula, and it looks like so:

$||\varphi''||_2^2=||s_n''||_2^2+||\varphi''-s_n''||_2^2\geq||s_n''||_2^2$

I find it hard to relate such algebraic expressions to the seemingly geometric nature of both the Euclidean normal form and the Pythagorean formula and would appreciate any help

Comment: it is $||f-p||_{2} = (\int (f(x)-p(x)^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. The integral is taken over the whole space. It is called the $L2$ norm, and you can study the L2 space which is a Banach space with functions in whos norm is finite.